# how can implemented adding more views in dynamic layout implementing scrollview in android

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

i am implementing  custom linearlayout in this adding more views retrieve database using webservices  in back ground process all data are retrive messages and message related userimages also  first initally loading messages after one by one loading images in custom linear layout

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/white"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/person" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                <TextView android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

codefile:

```
public class MYlist extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    List<MessageClass> messages;
    int i=0,n=5;
     ParseXMLString parse=new ParseXMLString();
     DataParsingComm dataparsing=new DataParsingComm();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String xml="<spGetUserMessages><SearchLocation></SearchLocation><LoginUserID>125</LoginUserID></spGetUserMessages>";
        messages =parse.GetGetUserMessages(dataparsing.ILGetUserMessages(xml));


        addElements(messages,i,n);
    }

    protected void addElements(final List<MessageClass> messages2,int i,int n) 
    {
        int k=0;
     //((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1)).removeAllViews();

        for(int i1=i;i1<n;i1++)
        {
            LinearLayout ll1=((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2));
            ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabmessage);
            Log.v("11111111","333"+ i1+ n);
          if(k==i1)
          {
            for(int j1=i1;j1<n;j1++)
            {

            TextView msg=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
            msg.setText(messages2.get(j1).getmessage());

            }
          }
            ImageView prsnImg=((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.person));
        try{
            String photoXml="<spGetUserPhoto><UserID>125</UserID></spGetUserPhoto>";

            String photoInfoFromDB=new DataParsingComm().ILGetImage(photoXml);

            if(photoInfoFromDB.equalsIgnoreCase("anyType{}")||photoInfoFromDB.equals(null) )
            {
                prsnImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.person);
            }
            else{

                byte[] imgArry= Base64.decode(photoInfoFromDB);

                Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArry,0,imgArry.length);

                prsnImg.setImageBitmap(bit);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
            {
                System.gc();
                System.runFinalization();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

screenshot: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8437c22cca.png

my problem is every time display one item all data override that single item view in layout how can implemented one by one display views in linear layout

please tell me some solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are always selecting the same two objects...

There is a very basic way of obtaining what I think you might want:

main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/white" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        LinearLayout topLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        topLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);
            TextView textView = new TextView (this);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
            textView.setText("Text View #" + i);

            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);

            topLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);          

        }

        scrollView.addView(topLinearLayout);

    }
```

You can also define the `topLinearLayout` object in the xml file. It is up to you.

Comment: I updated my answer with some basic code that you can find useful.